# mov %eax,(%esp)

Tags: assembly, x86, att, mov, addressing-mode

What is the difference between the following statements?

```
mov %eax,%esp
mov %eax,(%esp)
```

I'm working on diffusing a binary bomb and am having trouble with a few of the `mov` and `leal` commands early on in the assembly.

Comment: One copies the register. The other loads from the memory it points to.

Comment: @Mysticial: This is AT&T syntax, so everything is backwards -- %esp and (%esp) are the destinations, not the sources.

Comment: @JerryCoffin AHHHH!!! I always fall for that trap...

Comment: Other memory addressing-modes are possible, not just register-indirect. 
 See [A couple of questions about \[base + index\*scale + disp\] and AT&T disp(base, index, scale)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27936196)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This copies the value in %eax into %esp.

```
mov %eax,%esp
```

This copies the value from %eax to the location in memory that %esp points to.

```
mov %eax,(%esp)
```

Comment: The latter is essentially pop eax without the decrement of esp

Comment: @Goaler444: No, it's storing to memory, so it's like a push, except actually overwriting the last dword pushed.