# A couple of questions about [base + index*scale + disp] and AT&T disp(base, index, scale)

Tags: assembly, x86, att, addressing-mode, intel-syntax

The general form for memory addressing in Intel and AT&T Syntax is the following:

```
[base + index*scale + disp]      # Intel, including GAS .intel_syntax noprefix
disp(base, index, scale)         # AT&T
```

My questions are the following:

- Can `base` and `index` be any register?
- What values can `scale` take, is it 1, 2, 4 and 8 (with 1 being the default)?
- Are `index` and `disp` interchangeable (with the only difference being that `index` is a register while `disp` is an immediate value)?

Comment: Related: [What is the meaning of MOV (%r11,%r12,1), %edx?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2883850)

Comment: Also some AT&T addressing mode examples in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info

Comment: Somewhat related: [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34058101) for more about different subsets of the general form and when you might use them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is described in Intel's manual:

> **3.7.5 Specifying an Offset**
> The offset part of a memory address can be specified directly as a static value (called a displacement) or through
> an address computation made up of one or more of the following components:
>
> - **Displacement** — An 8-, 16-, or 32-bit value.
> - **Base** — The value in a general-purpose register.
> - **Index** — The value in a general-purpose register.   [can't be ESP/RSP]
> - **Scale factor** — A value of 2, 4, or 8 that is multiplied by the index value.

The offset which results from adding these components is called an effective address.

The scale-factor is encoded as a 2-bit shift count (0,1,2,3), for scale factors of 1, 2, 4, or 8.  And yes, `*1` (shift count = 0) is the default if you write `(%edi, %edx)`; that's equivalent to `(%edi, %edx, 1)`

---

In AT&T syntax, it's `disp(base, index, scale)` - constants go outside the parens.  Some Intel-syntax assemblers also allow syntax like `1234[ebx]`, others don't.  But AT&T syntax is rigid; every component of the addressing mode can *only* go in its proper place.  For example:

```
movzwl  foo-0x10(,%edx,2), %eax
```

does a zero-extending 16-bit ("word") load into EAX, from the address `foo-0x10 + edx*2`.  EDX is the index register, with scale-factor 2.  There is no base register.  `foo` and `-0x10` are both part of the displacement, both link-time constants.  `foo` is a symbol address that the linker will fill in and subtract 0x10 from (because of the `-0x10` assemble-time offset).

If you have the choice, use just a base instead of an index with a scale of 1.  An index requires a SIB byte to encode, making the instruction longer.  That's why compilers choose addressing modes like `8(%ebp)` to access stack memory, not `8(,%ebp)`.

See also [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes) for more about when you might use a base, and/or index, and/or displacement.

---

A 16-bit displacement is only encodeable in a 16-bit addressing mode, which uses a [different format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55657904/why-dont-x86-16-bit-addressing-modes-have-a-scale-factor-while-the-32-bit-vers) that can't include a scale factor, and has a very [limited selection of which registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474010/nasm-x86-16-bit-addressing-modes) can be a base or index.

So a mode like `1234(%edx)` would have to encode the 1234 as a 32-bit `disp32` in 32-bit machine code.

Byte offsets from -128 .. +127 can use a short-form 8-bit encoding.  Your assembler will take care of this for you, using the shortest valid encoding for the displacement.

---

All of this is identical in 64-bit mode for 64-bit addressing modes, with disp32 also being sign-extended to 64-bit just like disp8.

64-bit mode does add a new different addressing mode, `symbol(%rip)` which doesn't work with any general-purpose registers, only a 32-bit offset from RIP.  See *[How do RIP-relative variable references like "[RIP + _a]" in x86-64 GAS Intel-syntax work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745872/how-do-rip-relative-variable-references-like-rip-a-in-x86-64-gas-intel-sy)* which also covers AT&T syntax.

Comment: I'm still not exactly sure what is a general purpose register, are all of the following considered to be general purpose registers: EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX, ESI, EDI, EBP, and ESP?

Comment: Yes (except `ESP` is excluded from the Index part). See figure 3-11 (_"Offset (or Effective Address) Computation"_) in the manual.

Comment: Let's mention one more minor difference between *base* and *index*: when EBP or ESP is used as *base* register, default segment is SS, otherwise it is DS.    MOV EAX,[EDI+EBP] loads EAX from data segment but MOV EAX,[EBP+EDI] from stack segment. Nevertheless, in Window flat model it doesn't matter, as both DS and SS contain the same segment descriptor.

Comment: In Long mode, what differences are there?

Comment: @PaulStelian: See [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes/34058400#34058400) for how addressing modes work, including 64-bit mode.