# Converting [symbol + constant] Intel syntax addressing mode to AT&T syntax?

Tags: assembly, offset, att, addressing-mode, intel-syntax

I just cant figure out how to add an offset to my destination when moving a value, specifically in Intel syntax I have:

```
MOV   [gdtr + 2], EAX
```

and for AT&T syntax I have tried converting it to:

```
movl %eax, gdtr(2,1)
```

which gives an error when compiling `junk '(2,1)' after expression` but using just `gdtr(,1)` works fine.

I don't understand why I cant use base offset, and only the scale factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply write

```
movl %eax, gdtr+2
```

Base-offset addressing only works when the offset is a register.  There's no point in having an addressing mode to add two constants together; the way this works (regardless of syntax) is that the assembler / linker resolve `symbol+constant` into a a single number for the displacement field of the instruction encoding.

Comment: You can also switch your assembler to intel syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I didn't realize you could do it like this in AT&T. And yes I suppose I could rewrite my code in Intel style, but I already have a good amount in AT&T. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

It's just `gdtr+2`

> `gdtr(2,1)` [gives an error] but using just `gdtr(,1)` works fine.

**The stuff inside the `()` parens in an AT&T addressing mode can only be registers (and a scale factor): `disp(base, index, scale)`.  Base and index are optional so empty is fine but invalid (non-register) is not.**

And when you specify a scale with no base or index, apparently you must use only one comma: `(,,1)` is an error about an empty scale factor.
You could write it as `gdtr+2(,1)` to explicitly use no registers.

**The +2 is part of the displacement in an addressing mode, not the base or index registers, regardless of syntax**.  See [A couple of questions about [base + index*scale + disp]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936196/a-couple-of-questions-about-base-indexscale-disp) or Intel or AMD's manual about how addressing modes are encoded.  (What you're doing is the `[disp32]` or `[disp16]` addressing mode, in terms of how it's going to be encoded into machine code.)

As Nate pointed out, the linker takes care of turning assemble-time literal constants + link-time-constant symbol addresses into a final address in the machine code, encoded as a `disp32` (or `disp16` for 16-bit address size).  Or RIP-relative `rel32` for x86-64.

Fun fact: some AT&T assemblers accept `(gdtr)` as an alternative to `gdtr`, but not `2(gdtr)`.

---

### Ways to solve this yourself:

Normally if you're stuck on NASM -> AT&T you can assemble NASM source (e.g. `nasm -felf`) and disassemble with an AT&T disassembler like `objdump -drwC`.  But that doesn't help here for symbolic addressing mode syntax because at best `objdump -dr` just annotates numeric addressing modes with symbol name info.

So in this case your best bet is to get GCC or clang to emit an instruction that uses a symbol name and a numeric constant, like this

```
char gdtr[1024];                // global var so it has a symbol
char foo() { return gdtr[2]; }  // load from global symbol + constant.
```

compiles with [`gcc9.3 -O2 -m32` **on the Godbolt compiler explorer**](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:3,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:3,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:3,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:3),source:'char+gdtr%5B1024%5D%3B%0Achar+foo()+%7B+return+gdtr%5B2%5D%3B+%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g93,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O2+-m32',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) to this asm:

```
foo:
        movzbl  gdtr+2, %eax
        ret
gdtr:
        .zero   1024
```

There's your addressing mode, and as a bonus the AT&T mnemonic for movzx with a byte source.  Of course you can fiddle with the types.

Compilers are useful resources; they know how to do lots of things "the normal way" when compiling simple C functions, and they know the calling convention and type widths.  And AT&T syntax for everything including function pointers.  **If you're stuck, ask a compiler**.  Basically the only thing you can't get a compiler to show you is the syntax for `jmp far` (AT&T `ljmp`)