# What does `a+y(%reg)` do in AT&T syntax

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86-64, att, musl

I am translating musl's x86_64 [sigsetjmp](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/signal/x86_64/sigsetjmp.s) into intel syntax but cannot figure out what the following two lines of assembly are doing:

```
mov %rbx,72+8(%rdi)
...
mov 72+8(%rbx),%rbx
```

My guess is it is getting the value at 8(%rdi) and adding 72 to it. But I can't find a way to do that in intel syntax so not sure. I haven't found anything online that explains what this syntax is doing.

Comment: Nope. the same as writing `mov %rbx, 80(%rdi)` which is mov value in RBX to memory address [80+rdi] . Same as `mov [rdi+72+8],rbx` or `mov [rdi+80],rbx`. The reverse for the last line.

Comment: I should clarify I guess. 80 (or 72+8) is added to the value in RDI and that is treated as the memory address.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [A couple of questions about \[base + index\*scale + disp\] and AT&T disp(base, index, scale)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27936196) which includes an `foo-0x10(,%edx,2)` addressing-mode example.  But a duplicate specifically about constant expressions as assemble-time constants might be better, and the fact that you can't load-and-add except with a memory-source `add` instruction like `mov $72, %ebx` / `add 8(%rdi), %rbx`.  That seems to be the crux of the confusion here.

Comment: [Converting \[symbol + constant\] Intel syntax addressing mode to AT&T syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61090374) is related.

Comment: That answers my questions thanks! I overlooked that because it was talking about in relation to a `foo` symbol rather than a constant. I knew you couldn't move into a constant which was making me even more confused :)

Comment: Technically a symbol is just a constant memory address that the assembler is managing for you.