# Confusion about addressing modes - how does a register by itself outside () work as an ADDRESS_OR_OFFSET constant?

Tags: assembly, x86, terminology, att, addressing-mode

In [Programming from the Ground Up](https://www.academia.edu/1247519/Programming_from_the_Ground_Up), in chapter 3 I read

> The general form of memory address references is this:
>
> ```
> ADDRESS_OR_OFFSET(%BASE_OR_OFFSET, %INDEX, MULTIPLIER)
> ```
>
> All fields are optional. To calculate the address, simply perform the following calculation:
>
> ```
> FINAL ADDRESS = ADDRESS_OR_OFFSET + %BASE_OR_OFFSET + MULTIPLIER * %INDEX
> ```
>
> `ADDRESS_OR_OFFSET` and `MULTIPLIER` must both be constants, while the other two must be registers. If one of the pieces is left out, it is just substituted with zero in the equation.

Now, I assume that *substituted with zero* is a typo, because if `MULTIPLIER`'s default was 0, then the value of `%INDEX` would be irrelevant, as the product would always be zero anyway ([indeed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27937263/5825294)). I guess 0 is default for the other 3?

Nonetheless, what confuses me the most is that form the description above I understand that parenthesis and commas have the function of determining which parts of what we write map to the 4 "operands" of the addressing.

But then, in the following chapter I read

> For example, the following code moves whatever is at the top of the stack into `%eax`:
>
> ```
> movl (%esp), %eax
> ```
>
> If we were to just do
>
> ```
> movl %esp, %eax
> ```
>
> `%eax` would just hold the pointer to the top of the stack rather than the value at the top.

But I don't understand why. I mean,

- given the `FINAL ADDRESS` expression above, I would say that

  - if we put `%esp` in parenthesis, it will play the role of `%BASE_OR_OFFSET`, with `ADDRESS_OR_OFFSET` and `%INDEX` defaulting to 0 and `MULTIPLIER` to 1,
  - if we put `%esp` not in parenthesis,  it will play the role of `ADDRESS_OR_OFFSET`, with `%BASE_OR_OFFSET` and `%INDEX` defaulting to 0 and `MULTIPLIER` to 1,

  and the sum would still be the same.
- Furthermore, how is `%esp` constant?

  - Maybe I'm making the mistake of thinking that it is not constant because I think about the *content* of `%esp`?
  - If that's the case, and `%esp` is constant becasue is the name of a physically fixed register, then what is a non constant, in this context?

Comment: The book appears to make a very general statement, though qualifies that it is about *memory (address) references*.  There are other addressing modes, such as register direct, which is what `%esp` is in that `movl` w/o ()'s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, the default multiplier is `1`.

---

**`movl %esp, %eax` isn't using a memory addressing-mode *at all*.**  It's a register-direct operand, so it's syntactically different from `mov symbol_name, %eax` (a load from an absolute address).

There's a register but it's not inside `()` so the `disp(base,idx,scale)` syntax doesn't apply.

In machine code, the ModRM byte's 2-bit "mode" field uses `0b11` to encode that it's a register operand instead of memory.  (The other 3 encodings select memory with no displacement vs. disp8 vs. disp32: https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#ModR.2FM_and_SIB_bytes.  And see also *[rbp not allowed as SIB base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522544/rbp-not-allowed-as-sib-base)* for the fun special cases that allow `disp32` with no registers, and to make the SIB byte optional to save machine-code size for simple addressing modes.)  With ModR/M.mode = `11`, the field is just a simple register number.  Similarly in assembly language, when you use a bare register name, you just get the register operand directly, not using it as an address to access memory.

(I'm not sure this is a useful analogy, but I think the useful point is that a register operand is a different thing from a memory operand even in x86 machine code.  They are qualitatively different and need to be distinguished.)

---

Also related:

- [What happens if I omit the scale factor of and indexed addressing mode in x86 AT&T syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67711469/what-happens-if-i-omit-the-scale-factor-of-and-indexed-addressing-mode-in-x86-at) - duplicate for the scale-factor error in that book, it should be `1` not `0`.  The **shift count** is `0` in the machine code, but source-level asm syntax uses power-of-2 multipliers (in all x86 assembly syntaxes I've ever seen, including AT&T, all flavours of Intel, and Go's assembly dialect.  It would of course be possible to invent a new syntax that used shift counts in the asm source.)
- [A couple of questions about [base + index*scale + disp] and AT&T disp(base, index, scale)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936196/a-couple-of-questions-about-base-indexscale-disp-and-att-dispbase-inde) AT&T vs. Intel syntax and how to break down the components of an addressing mode.
- [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes) - what the machine can do, and how each combination of components might make sense with a static array.
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info