# Is LEA valid with a negative scale, or SUB with a scaled register?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers, machine-code, instructions

I have two registers mapped like this to a variable

%rdi = x, %rsi = y

I want to make y = y - 4x

My trial goes like this. I subtracted x four times to get y - 4x.

```
subq %rdi, %rsi         # y = y - x
subq %rdi, %rsi         # y = y - 2x
subq %rdi, %rsi         # y = y - 3x
subq %rdi, %rsi         # y = y - 4x
```

But I want to finish with just one line of code.

I thought about using leaq in this situation.
`leaq (%rsi, %rdi, 4), %rsi    # y = y + 4x`

But as you see, now I'm adding 4x instead of subtracting 4x.

**So my question is,**

1. **leaq (%rsi, %rdi, -4), %rsi** 
   would this be a vaild operation? I know the scaling factor has to be a power of 2 like 1,2,4... but can it be a negative number like -4?
2. **subq -4 * %rdi, %rsi**
   would this also be valid? I want to know if I could perform a multiplication to a register value directly.

Comment: No, any assembler would have told you those don't assemble.  And [Intel's manual for SUB](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sub) could tell you why: there operand can only be register or memory, not a scaled-register.  This isn't ARM with a barrel-shifter for source operands.  You can of course do it in 2 instructions with a temporary register, shift or LEA then sub.

Comment: As for the negative scale in an addressing mode, unfortunately no on that as well, there's only a 2-bit shift count in machine code. [A couple of questions about \[base + index\*scale + disp\]]([A couple of questions about \[base + index\*scale + disp\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27936196))  Basically a duplicate of that, except for the question about `sub`.

Answer (score 2):

> I know the scaling factor has to be a power of 2 like 1,2,4... but can it be a negative number like -4?

No. In machine code the scale is encoded as 2 bits (in a "SIB" byte, which also has 3 bits to determine the index register and 3 bit to determine the base register - there's no unused bits). The 2 scale bits are interpreted as a shift count (like `<< 0`, `<< 1`, `<< 2`, `<< 3`) which is essentially the same as a multiplier (like `* 1`, `* 2`, `* 4`, `* 8`).

> I want to know if I could perform a multiplication to a register value directly.

The scale can't be used directly on a register. This kind of complexity was added to make accessing arrays fast/easy; and can only be used to determine an address (either for loading an address with the `lea` instruction, or for accessing memory).

There are other instructions that do a multiplication to a register value though (shifts, `mul`, `imul`, and `aad` for general/integer registers, plus more for floating point and SIMD registers). If you want to do a "fused multiply and add" then your choices are `aad` (which is 8 bits where the multiplier has to be a constant), `lea`, and SIMD extensions.

> subq -4 * %rdi, %rsi

In theory; it would be possible to invent a new assembly language for 80x86 machine code (in the same way that AT&T invented an assembly language for 80x86 that doesn't match Intel's assembly language); where the assembler can do whatever it likes (as long as it can convert its idea of "instructions" into machine language).

For example, a new assembly language could accept `movq %rsi+%rdi*4, %rsi` (and convert it to the machine code for `leaq (%rsi, %rdi, 4), %rsi`). In the same way, a new assembler could accept `subq -4 * %rdi, %rsi` (and convert it to the machine code for `leaq (%rsi, %rdi, 4), %rsi`) as long as no later instruction depends on the flags.

Comment: If you allow complex expressions that need to expand to multiple instructions, you now have a compiler, not an assembler, for a new language.  You could *maybe* still call it an assembler if you limit it to expressions that can be done efficiently without a temporary register.  With a `+4` for sub, it would be borderline: `subq 4 * %rdi, %rsi` could have to expand to `neg %rdi` / `lea` / `neg %rdi` (or double-`neg` the destination register, for even worth critical-path latency).  Worse than mov/neg into a temporary, and much worse than if you can destroy the source input with just shl/sub.

Comment: But good point that `rsi -= -4 * rdi` is just `rsi += rdi*4` and can be done with a single LEA except for FLAGS; the two hypothetical instructions in the question aren't equivalent!  (I'd assumed they were meant to be and didn't look further.)