# How to read assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

```
add    -0x4(%rsp,%rbx,4),%eax
```

```
cmp    %eax,(%rsp,%rbx,4)
```

I got confused by this two lines, I know it is adding the first one and saving the value into eax, but I don't know how to read/think about the first part of adding. And same thing for the compare I don't really understand what I'm comparing

Comment: Depending on where that assembly comes from (whether you dumped it with the compiler, or it comes from elsewhere). If you generated it with, e.g. `gcc -S`, you may find reading Intel format a bit easier (I know I do, but it's just a personal preference). Regardless, if you generated it, you can add `-masm=intel` as an option and it will generate Intel syntax. If you were just handed the assembly, you are stuck with ATT.

Comment: The *Indexed Addressing* for the *source* address in the first line is `base_address(offset_address, index, size)`

Answer (score -3):

This syntax belongs to at&t. -0x4(%rsp,%rbx,4) on first line
so for sum the values ​​in the brackets and multiply by -4. sums with eax and the result of eax changes

```
add    -0x4(%rsp,%rbx,4),%eax
```

That means

```
eax = (rsp+rbx*4) - 4 + eax
```

The bottom line means:

```
cmp    %eax,(%rsp,%rbx,4)
```

cmp is the compare command. Greater than, less than, or equal to.
Comparing eax with (rsb+rbx+4). As a result, the following flags change
[image]

Comment: `-0x4(%rsp,%rbx,4)` means `rsp+rbx*4 - 4`. `cmp` also has the AT&T inverted operands order, so the table is wrong for AT&T. Also there are more flags that CF, ZF, SF and `cmp` is just a discarded-result `sub`.

Comment: Actually I am using intel syntax. And I more or less knew what At&T looked like. thanks for the fix

Comment: The number outside the parentheses is a displacement, not a multiplier. The third clause **in** the parentheses is a multiplier however, but only for the second clause.

Comment: See [A couple of questions about \[base + index\*scale + disp\] and AT&T disp(base, index, scale)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27936196) re: AT&T addressing modes.  `add    -0x4(%rsp,%rbx,4),%eax` is `add eax, [rsp+rbx*4 - 4]`, as an assembler + disassembler could tell you.